# C++ is giving different wrong results for same arithmetic expression

Tags: c++, integer, addition, integer-overflow

I have a very simple calculation where I calculate the distance between each individual cell to center  in a 2D space. I know that the O(n) solution is redundant and I derived the formula for O(1) solution. But what I am trying to understand is: **Why do these two analogous calculations give me two different results?**

Here is the expected (correct) result in Python (Both versions give the same result):

```py
result = 0;
n = 499993;
center = (n+1)//2;
for ii in range(1,center):
        result += (ii*ii*8);

print(result);
```

which outputs:

```
41664916690999888
```

And here are two versions in C++ with two completely different wrong results:

1)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    int n = 499993;
    int center = (n+1)/2;
    for(int ii = 1; ii < center; ++ii)
    {
        result += (ii*ii);
    }
    cout << result*8 << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
154435732281936
```

2. 

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    int n = 499993;
    int center = (n+1)/2;
    for(int ii = 1; ii < center; ++ii)
    {
        result += (ii*ii*8);
    }
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
6229295798864
```

**What is the reason of this behavior?**

For compiler I am using GCC with only -g flag

Online compiler for CPP that produces the same result: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I expect that at some point `ii*ii` will be too large for a 32 bit int. Remember since its int * int the calculation is done as an int not `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: Are you checking for integer overflow?

Comment: You are definitely overflowing. Use `unsigned long long` everywhere: https://onlinegdb.com/SJIlXTZIu

Comment: Changing ii to long fixed the issue... So I guess C++ calculates the results in registers also as integer? I thought that would not be necessary.

Comment: @Asil: I'm not sure what you mean by "results in registers also as an integer" the exprssion `ii*ii*8` has type `int`, so any result will be truncated to an integer before being promoted to the `unsigned long long` that it's being assigned to.

Comment: since ii * ii both operands are int so the calculation is done as an int. This is not related to registers.

Comment: In Python, integral values are unbounded.   In C++, all integral types are bounded, and can overflow.   Overflowing a signed type gives undefined behaviour - it doesn't magically ensure the large value can be represented.

Comment: For your second case, using `result += (8LL*ii*ii);` should fix things (forcing the calculation to be performed as long long). In your first case, you would need to declare `ii` as a long long, or cast one of the operands of the `*`.

Comment: @Asil *Why do these two trivial calculations give me two different results?* -- You have been fooled by Python's seamless handling of unbounded integers.  Internal in Python is special code to handle unbounded integers,   To do the same in C++, you have to provide the code to do this.  Either write your own unbounded integer class, or use a third-party library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical `int` (signed 32bit) can store only upto 2,147,483,647 (`2**31 - 1`).

The calculation of `ii*ii` will exceed this limit when `ii` becomes larger than 46340.

You are using `unsigned long long` for `result`, so casting to that before calculation will improve the behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long result = 0;
    int n = 499993;
    int center = (n+1)/2;
    for(int ii = 1; ii < center; ++ii)
    {
        result += (static_cast<unsigned long long>(ii)*ii); // add casting
    }
    cout << result*8 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Basically c++ compiler calculates first like so `unsigned long long result = <some result of ii*ii>` which means it calculates `ii * ii` first and since `ii` is `int` it keeps the result in `int` then it makes the conversion to `unsigned long long` at the `operator =`